# DbMigration seed sequence contains more than one element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have the following classes

```
public class Lookup
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Order{get;set;}
}

public class CatalogType:Lookup // this was added on Add-migration "Second"
{
}

public class Catalog:Lookup
{
     public int CatalogTypeId{get;set;} // this was added on add-migration "Second"

     public CatalogType CatalogType{get;set;}
}
```

and I already have data in the database in the table Lookups that represent group of lookup classes like gender, marital statuses, catalog, etc. and the Lookups table contains a row with `Name="General"` that was used by Catalog(i.e Discriminator field="Catalog")

in the Configuration file inside the Seed function I wrote this code

```
context.Lookups.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.Name, **p.GetType().FullName** },
            new CatalogType
            {
                Name = "General",
                IsActive = true,
                Order = 1,
            },
            new CatalogType
            {
                Name = "Custom",
                IsActive = true,
                Order = 2,
            });
  context.SaveChanges();
```

My problem: I tried first `context.Lookups.AddOrUpdate(p=>p.Name)` and when I try to make `update-database`, the migration fails "`sequence contains more than one element`"

Then I tried to use `p.GetType().Name` the error was:

> An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name.

Then I tried to use `p.GetType().FullName` and upon executing the `update-database` command, I got the following error:

> The properties expression 'p => new <>f__AnonymousType18`2(Name =
>   p.Name, FullName = p.GetType().FullName)' is not valid. The expression
>   should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net:
>   'Function(t) t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an
>   anonymous type: C#: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }' 
>   VB.Net: 'Function(t) New With { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'.

I know that the problem caused because Lookups table contains already the `Name="General"` but how to tell the EntityFramework to take the column discriminator into consideration while trying to AddOrUpdate method?

in other words, i might have same data for 2 different objects and i want to add data on adding migration, how to achieve this if i have for example red car, red door and i want to add red apple for example? it will not allow me in my current situation, how to solve this issue?

Hope my explanation for this problem was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
//but two lines below in "OnModelCreating" method in your Context

 modelBuilder.Entity<Lookup>().Map<Catalog>(m => m.Requires("IsCatalog").HasValue(true));
 modelBuilder.Entity<Lookup>().Map<CatalogType>(m =>m.Requires("IsCatalog").HasValue(false));

// then :
 context.Lookups.AddOrUpdate(p => new { p.Name , p.IsCatalog},
        new CatalogType
        {
            Name = "General",
            IsActive = true,
            Order = 1,
        },
        new CatalogType
        {
            Name = "Custom",
            IsActive = true,
            Order = 2,
        });
        //context.SaveChanges(); //if you used base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // then you don't need to save
```

Comment: this solution will create a column IsCatalog inside Lookup table right? i am trying to use the already existed column Discriminator

Comment: yes , if you didn't specify a Discriminator column like i did using  map<> (you can also specify type and value ) ... it will create its own Discriminator (Default Discriminator)  , anyway try to use it new {p.Name , p.Discriminator } .. Note : Default Discriminator type : bit (true/false)

Comment: i tried your code, the problem here i cannot add this mapping conditions because Catalog is a TPC and CatalogType is TPH, EF will not accept this implementation

Comment: the problem in not in TPH or TPC each alone, what i was trying to do is to combine TPH and TPC both inherited from same class Lookup which is not allowed when implementing the mapping conditions after googling it

Comment: i realised that , applying tph or tpc alone is possible but applying both for drived types !!! i didn't have to do it before , good luck :)

Comment: BINGO, edit your answer and i will give you the bounty

Answer (score 0):

after searching about this subject i came to this result

1. TPH will work with discriminator field to distinguish between derived classes
2. TPC does not depend on discrimintor field because the primary key of the inherited class is the same primary key of the derived class
3. when trying to add the data to the Catalog and i am putting constraint ( if Name repeated then make update else create), the EF failed to set the discriminator='Catalog' since it is TPC so the update will fail because table contains other data 'General'
4. when trying to add mapping conditions, this is not allowed by EF to use same inherited class for TPC and TPH at the same time.

hope this will help others fell in the same problem like me